# Add text to each column in csv

Tags: python, csv

I need a python script to add text in each column in csv files. There are 330 csv files in a folder with this format:

```
14-04-03T08:52:38;...
14-04-03T08:52:39;...
14-04-03T08:52:40;...
...
```

And i need this format (2014 instead 14):

```
2014-04-03T08:52:38;...
2014-04-03T08:52:39;...
2014-04-03T08:52:40;...
...
```

How can I realise that?

Example of my code with print:

```
import os
import sys 
import csv
dirList = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])
dirList.sort()
for sFile in dirList:
    changeFile = sys.argv[1] + sFile
    print changeFile          
    with open(changeFile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            print row[0]
```

With this output:

```
14-04-03T12:03:34
14-04-03T12:03:35
14-04-03T12:03:36
```

How can I add the "20" to the begin of each column?

Comment: I have added my code.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to open the file as a text file and read each line, then write '20'+line to an output file, delete original file and rename output as original.

Answer (score 0):

As you are reading each element of the CSV file, just parse and convert the date strings when you hit them.

you can do it the following way:

```
import time
import datetime

datetime.datetime(
    *(time.strptime("14-04-03T08:52:38","%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")[:6])
).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

So what does it do?

It takes one of your date strings as input, like `"14-04-03T08:52:38"` and parses it to a real timeobject. 
We transform this time object to a datetime object and output it reformatted with a different output for your Year, hence: `'2014-04-03T08:52:38'`

Now you just replace the values in your csv and off you go :-)

```
import os
import sys 
import csv
import datetime
import time

dirList = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])
dirList.sort()
for sFile in dirList:
    changeFile = sys.argv[1] + sFile
    print changeFile          
    with open(changeFile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            print datetime.datetime(
                      *(time.strptime(row[0],"%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")[:6])
                  ).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```